# How to setup index route on nested parent route in React Router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

**Details**: I have top level routing like this:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='/*' element={<HomePage/>} />
  <Route path='/movies/*' element={<MoviesPage/>} />
  <Route path='/profile/*' element={<ProfilePage/>} />
  <Route path='/people/*' element={<PeoplePage/>} />
  <Route path='/auth' element={<LoginPage/>} />
</Routes>
```

Let's look the specific nested route **/movies/***:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='' element={<Outlet/>}>
    <Route index path='top-rated/*' element={<TopRatedMoviesPage/>} />
    <Route path='popular/*' element={<PopularMoviesPage/>} />
    <Route path='recommended/*' element={<RecommendedMoviesPage/>} />
    <Route path=':id/details' element={<MovieDetails/>} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

**The problem**: When I try to access **/movies**, the expected behaviour should be that it navigates to **/movies/top-rated** route because of the **index** property on the **top-rated/*** route, but this is not happening. I don't know if I misunderstood the functionality behind *index* property and *Outlet* element, so I need anyone's help with this. I hope You understand the problem.

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably because your index route is mis-configured. It should not have a path as said from the documentation: [Index Route - A child route with no path that renders in the parent's outlet at the parent's URL.](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#index-route).

`index` does not give auto navigation upon reaching `/movies`. However, if you navigates manually to `/top-rated`, the component should be there.