# react router index route not showing as default

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a very simple page app, the index route does not work on it.

```
import { Routes, Route, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './routes/home/home.component.jsx'
import Heading from './components/Heading';

function Header () {
  return (
    <>
      <Heading />
      <Outlet />
    </>

  )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Header />} >
        <Route index path='home' element={<Home />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is what gets shown on default, only the navbar with no home index element:
[image]

My question is why is that happening and how to fix this when my code is basically non existent and I can't see where I made the mistake

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it does, I have the outlet where it should render, and it succeeds to render if the route is '/home' but on route '/' it's not rendering the index route.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70228775/how-to-setup-index-route-on-nested-parent-route-in-react-router-v6

Comment: I noticed just now that it was you that proposed an edit to my answer. I rejected the edit adding the `BrowserRouter` as it wasn't included in the code snippet in the original post. I'd assumed the router component was just higher up the ReactTree. Is there also some issue with a missing router in your actual code?

Answer (score 10):

While the `index` and `path` props are both optional, don't use both at the same time. The `path="home"` prop is overriding the `index` prop.

If you want the `Home` component to render on both `"/"` ***and*** `"/home"` then you'll need two routes for this. One specified as the index route and renders on the parent route's `"/"` path, and the other to render on the nested `"/home"` path.

Example:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Header />} >
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='home' element={<Home />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect to the specific route by default, set **index prop** on children element without **path** prop and pass to it `<Navigate to="/yourDefaultRoute" />` as element property:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
    createRoutesFromElements(
        <Route path="/" element={<Template />}>
            <Route index element={<Navigate to="/home" />} />
            <Route path="home" element={<Home />} />
```

Works fine for me. React router v6.x